# AppBar shows half of content

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone, uwp

I use AppBar for my application and AppBarButtons.

But ABB shows only half of title text and rest after opening AB.
I want to hide the text completely and show it only in case of opening AB.

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqFlU.png)

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="AppBarButton" x:Name="appBar">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar IsSticky="True" ClosedDisplayMode="Compact" Background="LightGray" >

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" >
            <AppBarButton x:Name="mapaStackPanel" Label="Mapa" Icon="Map" Click="MapaStackPanelClick" Style="{StaticResource appBar}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <AppBarButton x:Name="mojePolohaStackPanel"  Label="Moje poloha" Icon="Map" Click="MojePolohaClick" Style="{StaticResource appBar}"/>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="najdiNejblizsiStackPanel"  Label="Najdi Nejbližší" Icon="Map" Click="NajdiNejblizsiClick" Style="{StaticResource appBar}"/>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="navigujStackPanel" Label="Naviguj" Icon="Directions" Click="navigujStackPanel_Click" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource appBar}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Thank you,
VT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`CommandBar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.aspx) instead of the `AppBar`, due it is designed to provide a layout for `AppBarButton` and related command elements.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsSticky="True" ClosedDisplayMode="Compact" Background="LightGray" >
        <AppBarButton x:Name="mapaStackPanel" Label="Mapa" Icon="Map" Click="MapaStackPanelClick" Style="{StaticResource appBar}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <AppBarButton x:Name="mojePolohaStackPanel"  Label="Moje poloha" Icon="Map" Click="MojePolohaClick" Style="{StaticResource appBar}"/>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="najdiNejblizsiStackPanel"  Label="Najdi Nejbližší" Icon="Map" Click="NajdiNejblizsiClick" Style="{StaticResource appBar}"/>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="navigujStackPanel" Label="Naviguj" Icon="Directions" Click="navigujStackPanel_Click" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource appBar}"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Comment: Exactly what I meant ! :)