# Why does my AppBar appear as ClosedDisplayMode.Compact on Page load regardless of actual setting?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, mytoolkit

I'm porting a Win8.1 app to UWP for Win10 and experiencing a strange issue with the `AppBar`. We've tried using `CommandBar` instead of `AppBar`, but the issue still occurs for us. We're on the latest version of MyToolkit (2.5.16 as of this writing). Our views are derived like so:

`SomeView` derives from `BaseView` dervices from `MtPage` (derives from `Page`)

So, for a particular view (in this case, `HomeView`), the XAML looks like:

```
<views:BaseView
   x:Name="pageRoot"
   x:Class="OurApp.HomeView"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   xmlns:controls="using:OurApp.Controls"
   xmlns:views="using:OurApp.Views"
   xmlns:viewModels="using:ViewModels"
   xmlns:fake="using:ViewModels.Fake"
   mc:Ignorable="d" >
   <views:BaseView.TopAppBar>
      <AppBar>
         <controls:NavigationView
            x:Name="NavigationView">
            <controls:NavigationView.Context>
               <viewModels:NavigationViewModel />
            </controls:NavigationView.Context>
         </controls:NavigationView>
      </AppBar>
   </views:BaseView.TopAppBar>
   <!-- other stuff not relevant to AppBars, etc -->
</views:BaseView>
```

Where `NavigationView` is a `UserControl` that has some buttons, and `NavigationViewContext` and `NavigationViewModel` describe which buttons should be active on which page, and so forth.

The problem is that this results in a sort of half-open, half-closed `AppBar` appearance (almost but not quite exactly as if `ClosedDisplayMode` were set to `Compact`) like so:

[image]

After adding `ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal"` to the `<AppBar>` control, as alluded to in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244908/appbar-shows-half-of-content), the live visual tree confirms that the AppBar has `IsOpen = 0` and `AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Minimal`... but it still stubbornly appears half-open as in the screenshot above.

Strangely, if the user navigates away from `HomeView` to some other view and then back to it, the `AppBar` is correctly rendered with `AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Minimal` (!):

[image]

We've tried handling the view's `NavigatedTo` event and manually forcing `ClosedDisplayMode` to `Minimal`, but that doesn't affect the rendered output (and in any case, the live visual tree confirms that that is already being correctly set to `Minimal`).

Any ideas why this is happening, and/or how to cause the `AppBar` to be rendered with `ClosedDisplayMode = Minimal` without having to navigate first? I'm sure I could probably brute force this somehow, but I feel like there's probably a better way or I'm missing something pretty simple.

Comment: Have you tried editing a template and commenting the compact view portion?

Comment: No. The issue isn't that it's being set to `Compact` - the live visual tree confirms this - it's that it's somehow being rendered halfway open, which looks kind of as though it were set to `Compact`.

Comment: `AppBar` and `CommandBar` have an extensive collection of visual states and associated animations. Chances are one of those is responsible for the effect you're describing. It's a matter of finding out which one. Look [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299108.aspx).

Comment: Just by the name of it, it should be that `ClipGeometryTransform`.

Comment: Actually, just by adjusting `AppBarThemeMinimalHeight` or `AppBarThemeCompactHeight`, depending on `ClosedDisplayMode`, seems to do the job.

Comment: @jstreet Interesting.. I'll look into it. Can you add an answer with that thought and the code to do it.

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson : Yes, i may have to do it a little later though.

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson : i tried a few things but no luck so far... it always starts with whatever value is in `AppBarThemeCompactHeight`, no matter the mode being compact or minimal. It only synchronizes with the expected behavior after transitioning between opened and closed states at least once. Hopefully you or someone else will have better luck.

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson : I noticed that `MtPage` derives from `ContentControl`, and NOT `Page`, like you mentioned before. Also, the problem you're describing only happens for `MtPage` views, but not for a regular `Page` view. So, despite the name, `MtPage` may not be what it sounds like. In case you can derive your views from a regular `Page` and still use other resources from `MyToolkit`, that should do it.

Comment: could yu please create sample app with issue, because I've tried with `Page` and with `MyToolkitPage` and couldn't to reproduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just switch to `CommandBar`. `CommandBar` works out-of-the-box perfectly well, for both, `Minimal` and `Compact` modes. `CommandBar` is the recommended preferred control over `AppBar`. Apparently, the only reason for keeping `AppBar` is to minimize changes.

[AppBar - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.aspx).

> Important  You should use the AppBar only when you are upgrading a
>   Universal Windows 8 app that uses the AppBar, and need to minimize
>   changes. For new apps in Windows 10, we recommend using the CommandBar
>   control instead.

[image]

**Page:**

```
<paging:MtPage
x:Class="App3.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App3"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:paging="using:MyToolkit.Paging"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<paging:MtPage.Resources>
</paging:MtPage.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
</Grid>

<paging:MtPage.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="appbar1" ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal" >
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <local:MyUserControl1></local:MyUserControl1>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>
</paging:MtPage.TopAppBar>
```

**User Control:**

```
<UserControl
x:Class="App3.MyUserControl1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App3"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <AppBarButton Icon="Home" Label="Home"></AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back"></AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Rotate" Label="Rotate"></AppBarButton>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```